# When is the mututal information (MI) between two variables (say X and Y) strong enough?

Tags: mutual-information

I understand that the mutual information (MI) is a measure of information added to the variable X given the addition of variable Y. I also understand that a MI closer to 0 indicates that the new variable (say Y) does not add much information to X. However, when to consider that such variables are very similar? Is there any threshold on the literature? For example when MI <= 0.1, they are strongly correlated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y are uncorrelated the mutual information is said to be 0, as information gained about X conveys nothing about Y. At the same time if X and Y are related to each other by an invertible function the Mutual Information is high